# Set outcome of formula to working days

Tags: sql

I would like to change the outcome of a SQL statement formula to 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 (these are working days).

- Example 1: when I have day 1, minus 2 days the outcome should be 4.
- Example 2: when I have day 4, plus 2 days the outcome should be 1.
- Example 3: when I have day 5, minus 20 days, the outcome should be 5

At the moment I'm using a table as shown below (I have the input and days-back and the output is what i want to see):

```
Input,        days-back,        output:
1             0                  1

Input,        days-back,        output:
1             1                  5

Input,        days-back,        output:
1             2                  4

Input,        days-back,        output:
2             4                  3
```

P.s. I do not have a date, only day numbers.

I hope you understand what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have "days-back" greater than 5 you need to use the following formula:

```
((Input + ((5*days-back)-1) - days-back) % 5) + 1
```

> **How this works** - If you look at the prior formula you can see I'm adding 5 to input to make sure we are always positive before I subtract one and the days back.  I then mod by 5 and add the one back in so that we go from 1 to 5 instead of 0 to 4
>
> Since I don't know how large days-back is going to be I need something larger but I also need to have it not effect the mod 5 calculation so I just multiply it by 5.  I then subtract one (so I can add it later and offset 0 to 4 to 1 to 5) and we are done.

*prior answer below*

---

I note I missed the 5 case -- here is the formula that works for that:

```
((Input + 4 - days-back) % 5) + 1
```

---

*original answer*

You need to use use [modulus math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).  The formula you want is

```
(Input + 5 - days-back) % 5
```

Where `%` means modulus.  In SQL Server you can use `%` in Oracle it is `MOD`, etc -- it depends on the platform.

---

For those that care here is my DB2 test code:

```
WITH TEST_TABLE(input, days_back) AS
(
  VALUES
    (1,0),
    (1,1),
    (1,2),
    (2,4)
)
SELECT TEST_TABLE.*
       MOD(INPUT+4-DAYS_BACK,5)+1
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

Comment: Plus1 for being able to determine OP's question.  After multiple reads, I still had no idea what he was looking for.   However, IF output 5 was not a typo, I added little logic to trap zero

Comment: Dear Hogan, amazing how you responded so quickly and gave the right answer, it however needs some tweaking. The outcome cannot be 0 or negative (it should be 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5).  I used the following statement to test:      Create table TEST_input(Losdag varchar(255), Transporttijd varchar(255))

insert into TEST_input (Losdag, Transporttijd)
values
(1, 0), 
(1, 1), 
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(1, 5),
(1, 6),
(1, 7),
(1, 20),
(1, 40)
 SELECT * , ((Losdag + 5 - Transporttijd) % 5)
  FROM TEST_input 

DROP TABLE TEST_input

Comment: I'm sorry for the many edits, I tried to get the right layout but it didn't work (I will look up how to in a minute). The columns in the code above have a different header: input=losdag, days-back=transporttijd and the output is laaddag. The outcomes are only incorrect at line 2 (1,1, ? output should be 5), line 6 (1,6, ? output should be 5), and the outcomes of the last three should be (1,7, ?)4, (1, 20, ?)1 and (1,40, ?) 1. Your edited formula for the 5 case starts of perfect, however at 1,6,? is shows a 0 instead of 5 and at 1,7,? it shows -1 instead of 4.

Comment: @TruckTruck - I see what you did you have days back that are larger than 5.  ok I will put up a new formula for that

Comment: Thanks for your helpfulness, this helps me with this query and with understanding future queries!